# Angular: cross origin calling mockapi.io

Tags: angular, typescript

Could you please help me to find the error on this http service ?

[image]
Json:
http://5bf54a062a6f080013a34e5b.mockapi.io/tasks

Project
https://stackblitz.com/edit/redux-in-actions?file=src%2Fapp%2Fservices%2Ftask.service.ts

Comment: have you did proxy configuration for cross-origin issue?

Comment: if you are facing cross-origin issue the this one may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53372609/embed-angular-into-spring-application-and-access-spring-controllers-when-running/53372789#53372789