# Redirection to a page in angular6

Tags: java, html, angular, redirect

I have this scenario :-

I have to integrate Payment Gateway in a website.
We are using angular 6 on front-end and  springboot on backend.
Payment Gateway asks to post data in formurl-encoded so i am posting data in formurl-encoded.
Now it gives me cross origin access control error.
So what i have done now is i have created an api which takes formurl-encoded string and posts on their api.
Now their response code is 302 which is of redirection.
now i am getting a url and cookie from the headers.
but if i send this url and cokkie on frontend,i am unable to open page with desired output , that is unable to set cookie on the another domain in angular.

now i am getting the html but i am unable to create a page dynamically with that html in angular.

Please tell me solution of it in angular or javascript if there is.

My code is as follows :-

-> service.ts

```
makePayment(data: MakePaymentModel) {
        let body = new URLSearchParams();
        let headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
        for (let i in data) {
            if (data[i] != undefined) {
                body.append(i, data[i]);
            }
        }
        return this.http.post(this.resourceUrl2, body.toString(), { responseType: 'text', observe: 'response', withCredentials: false });
    }
```

it is to post form urlencoded string on api.

Resource.java

```
@PostMapping(value = "/make-payment")
    public ResponseEntity<String> makePayment(@RequestBody String request) throws IOException {
        byte[] postData = request.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        int postDataLength = postData.length;
        URL url = new URL(this.payementGatewayUrl+this.challanUrl);
        HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        conn.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postDataLength ));
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        try(DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream())) {
            wr.write(postData);
        }
        boolean redirect = false;

        int status = conn.getResponseCode();
        if (status != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            if (status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_TEMP
                || status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_PERM
                || status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_SEE_OTHER)
                redirect = true;
        }


        if (redirect) {
            // get redirect url from "location" header field
            String newUrl = conn.getHeaderField("Location");
            // get the cookie if need, for login
            String cookies = conn.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie");
            // open the new connnection again
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(this.payementGatewayUrl+newUrl).openConnection();
            conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookies);
            conn.addRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
            conn.addRequestProperty("Referer", "google.com");
        }

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer html = new StringBuffer();
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            html.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
        System.out.println("URL Content... \n" + html.toString());
        return ResponseEntity.ok("OK");
    }
```

It is post the data on their api And get back the redirection

Comment: to resolve cross origin error you can check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53372609/embed-angular-into-spring-application-and-access-spring-controllers-when-running/53372789#53372789

Comment: I strongly recommend investigating the `RestTemplate` Spring utility, because about 80% of your code is unnecessary (and it's hard to read).

Comment: i tried to create a proxy but it didn't worked

Comment: i have a code with rest template also but problem here is on client side backend is working fine

Comment: do you have `HttpInterceptor` in your angular app?

Comment: yes i have for authentication and notification purpose